# Button to increment contents of html file by one each press

Tags: html, button, web, increment

Im currently creating a website for my chickens that will have an "egg counter". I have a hidden part of the site that is password protected where I want to put a button that every time I press it, adds one to the egg value. Currently, I have an html file that has just the number in it which I have embedded into the site.

(this is the code that embeds the .html file)

```
        <h2><b>Egg Counter!<b/></h2>
        <p>So far our chickens have laid</p>
        <font size="20" color="#FFFFFF"><embed src="./eggs.html"></embed></font>
```

I'm a novice programmer and I'm not sure whether this is the right approach but I have no idea how to make the button that changes the egg value.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you want the data to persist? If you want it to persist, put in in a database and read the actual value from that. You can then have a button which runs a script that updates the value in the database.

Comment: I think what you need is some server side programing, otherwise the page will not be able to store the current egg count.

Comment: Sever side programming is no problem, I physically own the server, it's a raspberry pi in by backyard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want the number to be stored, so it's always showing and you can update it as and when your hipster chickens lay eggs. The previous answer will allow you to increment the number but only while you have the browser open.

I think the best way to do this is with PHP.

So first of all you want your page to be .php , lets say admin/loggedin.php.

You want to create a blank file in the same directory called eggs.txt , with the permissions 0755.

Then you want your form to look like this

```
<form method="POST" action="loggedin.php">
   <input type="text" name="num" value="0"/>
   <input type="submit" value="Chicken came first" name="eggs">
</form>
```

To explain the method / action:

```
method
```

is how you want to send the data to the

```
action
```

page.

Options are [$_POST](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) and [$_GET](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php), I don't think going into too much detail here will help.

action= is to tell the form what page to send this data to, in this case we've chosen to send it to the same page the form is on (loggedin.php).

So now once you submit that form we will have a $_POST['num'] available to us which contains the number you entered into the form input field.

To get this, you want to add at the top of your page: EDIT (have changed the section of code below - file_put_contents should of been inside the if($_POST['eggs']) {

```
<?php
//this checks to see if the form was submitted by checking 'eggs' is set.
if($_POST['eggs']) {
  // create a nicer variable for our egg number, it deserves a nice name.
  $egg = $_POST['num'];  
  //this will put the new number of eggs in our eggs.txt file 
  file_put_contents('eggs.txt',$egg);
}    
?>
```

[file_put_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) writes to a file

Next you want to be able to get that number from the file on your display page. To do this:

```
<div class="my_egg_count">
   <?php echo file_get_contents('eggs.txt'); ?> 
</div>
```

[file_get_contents()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) reads a file, echo 'echo's' from the server to client side.

Let me know if you have trouble with this, you don't want to end up with egg on your face.

EDIT:: try this

```
if(is_writeable('eggs.txt')) {
    if(file_put_contents('eggs.txt',$egg)) {
        echo 'File Updated';    
    }else {
        echo 'Error Updating File'; 
    }
}else {
    echo "Error: File Isn't Writeable [possibly named incorrectly, isn't in the correct location, or wrong permissions]";   
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying so quickly! I'm having a bit of trouble with the code that saves the value, I'm not sure where to place it. I've tried multiple locations but nothing seems to work. Could this be because the text document does not have the permissions?

Comment: It goes at the very top of the page with the form on it, before anything else. Have you created the text file? and if so change the permissions on it to 0755 (make it writeable)

Comment: Yes, I've already created the text file and made sure the names correspond and everything. Also I've made sure the permissions for the text file are set to 0755. And the form lets me enter a number and submit it but it does not get written into the file.

Comment: I have changed the code above, try again with the edit (on the if($_POST'eggs']) section of code

Comment: I changed the code and it still is not showing the entered value in the text file. The text file should be in the admin folder right?

Comment: it should be in the same folder as the form page is, I've added some error checking code please see EDIT at the bottom of my original answer

Comment: if that doesn't work then email me the entire web folder to johnfaldo@gmail.com and I'll have a look

Answer (score 1):

You can use the javascript onclick event to increment the number by 1 per click.

place this in your head section.

```
function incrementValue()
{
var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
value++;
document.getElementById('number').value = value;
}
```

Place this where you want the button to display.

```
<form>
<input type="text" id="number" value="0"/>
<input type="button" onclick="incrementValue()" value="Increment Value" />
</form>
```

Comment: While this does not explicitly answer his question it is by far the easiest to implement with javascript.
Only thing I would add is `<script>` tags around the function.